# Casting a const base reference to derived

Tags: c++, qt, casting, qt5

I have a problem, but I don't know if I solved it correctly or if there are more correct ways.

Now, I have two classes (and one inherits from the other):

```
class Data_Base
{
...
}

class Data_Error : public Data_Base
{
...
}
```

Now, in the overload of the equality operator, I have to cast the const reference to a base object to a derived object again, in order to test its members. At present I'm doing this:

```
bool Data_Error::operator==(const Data_Base &other) const
{
    if (Data_Base::operator !=(other))
        return false;

    const Data_Error &other_cast = (const Data_Error &)other;

    ... More tests on other_cast ...
}
```

Now, there is no possibility that at the cast moment the `other` variable is something else than `Data_Error`, since the `Data_Base` `==` operator (and the `!=` operator, since it is implemented as the negation of `==`) also checks for the type of the derived object, so it reaches that line only if the type is correct.

Now, is there any problem with this? Is there any "more correct" solution?

I'm working with Qt (5.7), so is there any "more QTish" solution?

Comment: Why would you compare a `Data_Error` to a `Data_Base` descendant? What meaning does it have to compare types on different branches in a hierarchy? Just stick to `bool Data_Error::operator==(const Data_Error&other) const`, I say.

Comment: @StoryTeller Because when I have a list of base types, I want to iterate on it to check if some of the items are equal to that. I simply call == on every item; in the function I check if the type is the same, otherwise they are not equal. But for this purpose, the type of other should be the base one, otherwise the program does not know how to compare two different branches

Comment: Is your `operator==` virtual? If it isn't, it won't work as you expect.

Comment: Yes, it is virtual in both the base class and in the derived (even if I don't plan to derive from the derived, so virtual in the derived is useless, but anyway...)

Comment: If you don't intend to derive from the derived class, make it [`final`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/final)

Comment: "const reference" There's no such thing as a const reference, only a reference to const

Answer (score 2, accepted):

C-style casts should be avoided. You can find why [here](http://stroustrup.com/bs_faq2.html#static-cast). You should use static cast instead:

```
const Data_Error &other_cast = static_cast<const Data_Error &>(other);
```

Or dynamic cast to check at runtime other is *effectively* of type Data_Error:

```
const Data_Error &other_cast = dynamic_cast<const Data_Error &>(other);
```

Comment: For these purposes dynamic cast is more suitable

Comment: I first added it, but was unsure of the behaviour with references. But you're right, I readded it

Comment: So the `dynamic_cast` solution is better? If so, what if the cast fails? Does it throw an exception or set `other_cast` to `nullptr`?

Comment: @frarugi87, `dynamic_cast` to references throws if it fails. A reference cannot be `nullptr`, mainly because it's not a pointer.

Comment: @АлександрЛысенко why would you say dynamic cast is more correct?  He states in the problem  "there is no possibility that at the cast moment the other variable is something else than Data_Error"

Comment: @frarugi87 if you know the type for sure, there's no reason to pay for a dynamic_cast when static_cast will do what you want.  A dynamic cast checks the vtable pointer and then does a static cast if it matches the desired type.. so just do the static cast since the check is unnecessary per your assertions in the question.

Comment: Yes, you are right. I forgot about meaning of base comparison

Answer (score 1):

The correct way is to use `dynamic_cast` on pointers, because it simply returns null if the object is not the correct derived type. Your example would become:

```
bool Data_Error::operator==(const Data_Base &other) const
{
    if (Data_Base::operator !=(other))
        return false;

    const Data_Error *other_cast = dynamic_cast<const Data_Error *>(&other);
    if (other_cast == nullptr) { // not the correct type
        return false;
    }

    ... More tests on *other_cast ...
}
```

Comment: Does this affect the "constness" of other?

Comment: Why would you use dynamic_cast for this?  If you know the type already you can static_cast it.  "there is no possibility that at the cast moment the other variable is something else than Data_Error"

Comment: @frarugi87: no, this is converting a const ref to a pointer to const. So *constness* is preserved here.

Comment: @xaxxon: other is passed as a `const Data_Base &`. It could be a plain `Data_Base` or any other possible derived type. `dynamic_const` is used here to detect that case.